# How to Add(+) 30 minutes to the DateTime.now in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically I have an access token that expires in 300 seconds, I need to add 30 minutes to the current date time and save that date time to check whether the access token is expired or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `add()` to add some time to `DateTime`, like this:

```
var result = DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes: 30));
print("now + 30 min = ${result}");
```